# Map MS Word 2010 Office symbols to Html unicode or MathML Symbol equivalent programmatically

Tags: html, ms-word, openxml, symbols, mathml

I want to read MS Word 2010 office symbols to equivalent HTML based unicode or MATHML Symbols equivalent.
I am currently using DrawString() to get image of the symbol, but it is bit blur and bold type.
I want to display it either as HTML Unicode or as MATHML Symbol, whichever is better and possible.
Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by “MS Word 2010 Office symbols”?

Comment: I mean symbols inserted in ms office word with font "symbol".

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the question is about mapping the Symbol font (commonly available in Windows) to Unicode or MathML. This font uses its own encoding, and it originally lacked exact definition (e.g., some glyphs are ambiguous and could be interpreted as different characters), but now we can regard the [Adobe Symbol Encoding to Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/symbol.txt) mapping as official. This mapping file is a plain text file in a specific format, so it can be read and parsed programmatically. It gives you the Unicode code number equivalent for each of the 256 code positions in the Symbol font. In MathML, you can use either the Unicode characters as such or as numeric references such as `&#x3a9;` for U+03A9 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA (Ω).

Note that the Symbol font is legacy software with some oddities. In particular, the mapping is from Unicode to Symbol font encoding rather than vice versa. When mapping in the other direction, e.g. converting legacy data in Symbol font format to Unicode, you need to make decisions. For example, both U+03A9 and U+2126 OHM SIGN map to 0x57 in Symbol font. This is a simple case: when mapping from Symbol font data to Unicode, 0x57 should map to U+03A9, according to principles set in the Unicode standard. There are more difficult cases where two different characters are possible and the choice should depend on context, such as GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA versus INCREMENT.